# com.SearchPlayer is not an enclosing class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i am creating class object of my player from SerchPlayer Class it generating =           "com.SearchPlayer is not an enclosing class" Error When i Run my project

Player player = new **Player()**;

```
import cz.msebera.httpclient.android.BuildConfig;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SearchPlayer {
    public ArrayList<Player> Player;

    public class Player implements Serializable {
        public static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
        public String FirstName;
        public String LastName;
        public String Role;
        public String personid;
        public String playerImg;

        public Player() {
            this.personid = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
            this.playerImg = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
            this.FirstName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
            this.LastName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
            this.Role = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inner class is not static and it needs an instance of its enclosing class to create an object. try

```
SearchPlayer x = new SearchPLayer();
SearchPlayer.PLayer y = x.new PLayer();
```

Comment: Thank you SO Much It is Work For Me..:)